# I am getting Unhandled Promise Rejection error and some data structure advise

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a new collection under a restaurant doc which has auto doc id. My new path will be /restaurants/restaurant(a document which has auto generated doc id)/ my new collection
I am getting an error in this line

```
db.collection('restaurants').doc(doc.id).add( {
```

Here is my Code

```
   <script>
        import PictureInput from 'vue-picture-input'
        import firebase from 'firebase';
        require('@/firebase/init')
        const db = firebase.firestore()
        export default {
          name: 'Newentry',
          data() {
            return {
              menuTitle: null,
              foodName: null,
              menuItemDescription: null,
              menuItemInfo: null,
              inputCalories: null,
              image: null,
              imageURL: null,
              feedback: null
            }
          },
          components: {
            PictureInput
          },
          methods: {
            onChanged() {
              if(this.$refs.pictureInput.file) {
                this.image = this.$refs.pictureInput.file
              } else {
                console.log("Please add image")
              }
            },
            onRemoved() {
             this.image = ''
            },
            addFood() {
              if(!this.menuTitle) {
                this.feedback = "Please enter a menu title in Menu Section Name"
              } else if(!this.foodName) {
                this.feedback = "Please enter a food name in Menu Item Name"
              } else if(!this.menuItemDescription) {
                this.feedback = "Please enter a description in Menu Item Description"
              } else if(!this.menuItemInfo) {
                this.feedback = "Please enter an info in Menu Item Info"
              } else if(!this.inputCalories) {
                this.feedback = "Please enter calory in Calorie"
              } else if (!this.image) {
                this.feedback = "Please add a photo"
              } else {
                this.feedback = null
                // set and upload image to database and get its url
                 const storageRef=firebase.storage().ref(`${this.image.name}`).put(this.image)
                 storageRef.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                   this.imageURL = url
                 })

                // get current user
                let user = firebase.auth().currentUser
                // find restaurant that same ownerid
                db.collection('restaurants').where('ownerID', '==', user.uid).get()
                .then(snapshot => {
                  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    db.collection('restaurants').doc(doc.id).add( {
                      foodLine: {
                        menuTitle: this.menuTitle
                      },
                      food: {
                        foodName: this.foodName,
                        menuItemDescription: this.menuItemDescription,
                        menuItemInfo: this.menuItemInfo,
                        inputCalories: this.inputCalories,
                        imageURL: this.imageURL
                      }
                    }).then(() => {
                      this.menuTitle = ''
                      this.foodName = ''
                      this.menuItemDescription = ''
                      this.menuItemInfo = ''
                      this.inputCalories = ''
                      this.image = ''
                    }).catch(err => {
                      console.log(err)
                    })
                  })
                })
              }
            }
          }

        }
        </script>
```

I search forums but none of them solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several points to be adapted in your code:

#### 1. `add()` is a method of a `CollectionReference`

The [`add()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.html#add) method is to be called on a `CollectionReference`, not on a `DocumentReference`.

Since you want the new document(s) to have a path "/restaurants/restaurant(a document which has auto generated doc id)/ my new collection" you need to do:

```
db.collection('restaurants').doc(doc.id).collection("my_new_collection").add()
```

#### 2. You should take into account the number of restaurant docs for a user

You don't specify if a given user can have one or more restaurants documents (in other words how many docs the `db.collection('restaurants').where('ownerID', '==', user.uid)` query will return).

If, for a given user, the query returns only **ONE** restaurant, you could adapt your code as follows:

```
db.collection('restaurants').where('ownerID', '==', user.uid).get()
.then(snapshot => {   //This is a QuerySnapshot
    return snapshot.docs[0].ref.collection("my_new_collection").add(...);
}).then(() => {
    this.menuTitle = '';
    //...
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

If, on the other hand, the query **may return several docs**, it is better to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows, in order to correctly chain the promises returned by the asynchronous methods:

```
db.collection('restaurants').where('ownerID', '==', user.uid).get()
.then(snapshot => {   
    const promises = [];
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        promises.push(doc.ref.collection("my_new_collection").add(...));
    })
    return Promise.all(promises);
}).then(result => {
    this.menuTitle = '';
    //...
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Note that, instead of using `Promise.all()` you could use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes). One of the difference with `Promise.all()`, is that a batch of writes completes atomically.

Comment: Thank you very much for your respond i will try as you show and want to ask you something i am doing this because i need to get data by restaurants each when user select a restaurant it will give only its in fo and menu hope i am doing right